# Rebuilding Conan package when dependency's option changes

Tags: conan

I have a package `foo` with an option called `option_a`, which controls a defines to be used when compiling `foo` and its consumers.

I also have a package `bar`, having `foo` as a dependency.

Finally, I have an application which depends on `bar` and transitively depends on `foo`.

The problem I have is that if I change `foo:option_a`, I need to recompile `bar` with the updated defines, otherwise my compilation fails. How can I signify in `bar`'s conanfile to include `foo:option_a` in its package_id, so that it recompiles of `option_a` changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading [Dependency Issues](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/define_abi_compatibility.html#dependency-issues) section in Conan Docs to understand how Conan ABI compatibility works, it will explain your case.

As solution, I recommend you using [full transitive mode](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/define_abi_compatibility.html#enabling-full-transitivity-in-package-id-modes), also explained at same documentation page.

Why don't Conan solves it by default?

Backward compatibility for version 1.x. New package id modes have been created to solve new problems, when 1.0 was released the most general case was solved by `semver_direct_mode`.